# How do I move related columns together in a grouped bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
    Product = c(755, 728, 417, 355, 913, 634, 385, 208, 204, 696, 968, 816, 279, 869, 823, 646, 986, 674, 806, 335, 731, 734, 107, 105, 512, 859, 159, 113, 353, 105, 205, 919, 243, 717, 838, 408, 423, 357, 408, 464, 724, 643, 943, 648, 623, 451, 449, 135, 842, 711),
    Category = c("Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese"),
    Sub_Category = c("White", "Camembert", "White", "Camembert", "White", "Brie", "Brown", "Wholemeal", "White", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Gouda", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "Brown", "White", "Wholemeal", "Gouda", "Gouda", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "White", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Brown", "Brie", "Brie", "White", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "Gouda", "White", "Wholemeal", "Brown", "White", "Camembert", "Brie", "Brie", "Camembert", "Brie", "Camembert", "Gouda", "Camembert", "Wholemeal", "White", "Camembert"),
    Fibre = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)
```

With which I have the following script to produce a plot:

```
library(tidyverse)

proportions <- df %>%
  group_by(Category, Sub_Category) %>%
  summarise(Proportion = mean(Fibre == TRUE) * 100, .groups = 'drop')

ggplot(data = proportions, aes(x = Proportion, y = Sub_Category, fill = Category)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  labs(fill = "Category")
```

[image: Bar Chart]

This is very close to the output I am hoping for.

However, I want the bars to be grouped by category (so all the bread bars should be together, and then the cheese bars together) and ordered in descending value after this grouping. So the final order of bars read from top to bottom should be white, wholemeal, brown, brie, camembert, gouda.

**How can I reorder my bars so that they are grouped both by category and ordered by descending value?**

Comment: Order the levels attributes of sub-categories within the major categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `interaction()` for this:

```
ggplot(data = proportions, 
       aes(x = Proportion, 
           y = interaction(Sub_Category, Category), 
           fill = Category)
       ) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev) + 
  labs(fill = "Category")
```

You will get adjusted labels for y axis as well:
[image]

**Correction**

As I have noticed that you need arranging by Proportion you may use this:

```
proportions %>%
mutate(Sub_Category2 = factor(Sub_Category, 
                                ordered = T, 
                                levels = arrange(.,  rev(Category), rank(Proportion, ties.method = "random")) %>% 
                                  pull(Sub_Category)
                                )
  )  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Proportion, y = Sub_Category2, fill = Category)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  labs(fill = "Category")
```

[image]

Comment: @Jay-Bee Please find posted my edited answer

Comment: Hi @asd-tm, when I run the correction code I get an error: `Error in mutate(): ℹ In argument: Sub_Category2 = factor(...). Caused by error: ! object '.' not found`

Comment: @JayBee.please find editrd

Answer (score 2):

I would facet on `Category` and, as IRTFM mentioned, reorder the levels of `Sub_Category`. One way to do that is to use the `fct_reorder` function from the **forcats** package. And you don't need to dodge here.

```
library(forcats)

ggplot(data = proportions, 
       aes(x = Proportion, 
           y = fct_reorder(Sub_Category, Proportion))) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Category), 
           show.legend=FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~Category, scales="free", labeller=label_both)
```

[image]

And if you want all the bars to appear in one plot, the following adjustment can be made:

```
ggplot(data = proportions, 
       aes(x = Proportion, 
           y = fct_reorder(Sub_Category, Proportion))) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Category), 
           show.legend=FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~Category, scales="free_y", 
             labeller=label_both, 
             nrow=2,
             strip.position = "right") +
  labs(y="Sub-category") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]